# How to find all a tags with aria-label attribute BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to find all a tags that have an aria-label attribute (not trying to find a tags with any specific value for the attribute, just every tag that has the attribute in general). My code is shown below. When I run the code, I get an error indicating that the aria-label parameter cannot be parsed. How can I do this correctly?

```
url = 'https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?type=Experiment&control_type!=*&status=released&perturbed=false&assay_title=TF+ChIP-seq&assay_title=Histone+ChIP-seq&replicates.library.biosample.donor.organism.scientific_name=Homo+sapiens&biosample_ontology.term_name=K562&biosample_ontology.term_name=HEK293&biosample_ontology.term_name=MCF-7&biosample_ontology.term_name=HepG2&limit=all'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
a_tags = soup.findAll('a', aria-label=True)
for tag in a_tags:
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Comment: Has the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS selector `a[aria-label]` which will select all `a` that have the attribute `aria-label`.

To use a CSS selector, use [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of `find_all()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?type=Experiment&control_type!=*&status=released&perturbed=false&assay_title=TF+ChIP-seq&assay_title=Histone+ChIP-seq&replicates.library.biosample.donor.organism.scientific_name=Homo+sapiens&biosample_ontology.term_name=K562&biosample_ontology.term_name=HEK293&biosample_ontology.term_name=MCF-7&biosample_ontology.term_name=HepG2&limit=all'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
a_tags = soup.select('a[aria-label]')
for tag in a_tags:
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Or: use the `attr=` argument:

```
a_tags = soup.findAll('a', attrs={"aria-label": True})
```

Or: Check if `aria-label` is in the `.attrs`:

```
a_tags = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and "aria-label" in tag.attrs)
```

---